# Generating a 'wave-based sine wav' sound, verses a regular sine wav sound

Tags: python, numpy, wav, pyaudio

I saw a question posted on Stack Overflow about generating a sound based on a sine wav in Python. Here was the code that produced the output I was looking for:

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 1.0   # in seconds, may be float
f = 440.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
            channels=1,
            rate=fs,
            output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
stream.write(volume*samples)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

What if instead of me using the line...

```
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)
```

I want to write whatever lines of code it would take, to where the samples (numpy array) would contain the values of a certain 'position' inside a specific wave file instead. Example, if I have a .wav file that has a sine wav stored inside the .wav file, and the .wav file is 1 second long, then it would *'replace'* the line of code above. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to load a WAV file into a numpy array?

Comment: Yes. I would like to 'replace' the sine wave (generated with the sin() function) with a .wav file that consists of a sine wav instead.